# Ubuntu 22.04 lags and auto-close application with just few applications open

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to the Linux ecosystem and have Ubuntu 22.04 installed alongside Windows 10 on my computer in a dual boot configuration.

Primarily, I use Ubuntu for web development, I usually have Chrome with about six tabs open, VSCode, a Docker container running in the background, Spotify, and sometimes Postman.

When only browsing the internet with just Chrome open, everything works fine. However, when I have both VSCode and Chrome open with a Docker container running in the background, my computer lags and the applications often auto-close. Can someone suggest a solution to this issue? Do I simply need to install more RAM or is it possibly related to the way I set up or installed Ubuntu?

For context, my computer has a Ryzen 3 2200G processor with 2x4GB of RAM.

Let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 1):

These seem like classic symptoms of an low-on-memory condition.

- Sluggish behavior suggests that you are too low on RAM and the system is swapping memory to disk to stay alive.
- Surprise terminations suggest that RAM+Swap is too full, and the system is reluctantly jettisoning processes in a final desperate attempt to avoid a hard crash.

Use the `free` command before, during, and after a sluggish time to check your RAM and Swap usage. Also use `free` to check that all your currently-installed RAM is recognized by the system.

You can add more Swap to prevent terminations.

You can use fewer memory-hungry processes simultaneously to reduce swapping.

You can add RAM.